# Image task for centering some text

Tags: image

I am wanting to add some text to an image. Currently I am using Paint Shop Pro 9. I am finding it a little bit hard too center some text correctly in the middle.

Is there some free software that I can use to do this task easily and effectively.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A lot of base photo processing functions are available in the [Google Picasa](http://picasa.google.com/)